# Is EKS Nodegroup really necessary

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a few questions on EKS node groups.

1. I dont understand the concept of Node group and why is it required. Can't we create an EC2 and run kubeadm join for joining EC2 node to EKS Cluster. What advantage does node group hold.
2. Does node groups (be it managed or self-managed) have to exist in same VPC of EKS cluster. Is it not possible to create node group in another VPC. If so how?

Answer (score 1):

1. [managed node groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html) is a way to let AWS manage part of the lifecycle of the Kubernetes nodes. For sure you are allowed to continue to configure [self managed nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/worker.html) if you need/want to. To be fair you can also spin up a few EC2 instances and configure your own K8s control plane. It boils down to how much you wanted managed Vs how much you want to do yourself. The other extreme on this spectrum would be to use [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html) which is a fully managed experience (where there are no nodes to scale, configure, no AMIs etc).
2. the EKS cluster (control plane) lives in a separate AWS managed account/VPC. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-networking.html). When you deploy a cluster EKS will ask you which subnets (and which VPC) you want the EKS cluster to manifest itself (through ENIs that get plugged into your VPC/subnets). That VPC is where your self managed workers, your managed node groups and your Fargate profiles need to be plugged into. You can't use another VPC to add capacity to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for picking this question @mreferre.

Regarding the 1st question, I am still confused. My understanding is that there 3 ways to manage worker nodes which are Managed, self-managed and spinning up our own EC2. Am i right? And frankly speaking I still dont understand the different between managed and self managed

Comment: Mh.. what are you basing your understanding from? We basically have a managed way (node groups) and an un-managed way (bring your own EC2 instances to the cluster). What you <may> be referring to is the fact that managed node groups can be configured with our default launch template OR you can specify your own custom launch template ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html)). The nodes are still "managed" but with the custom launch template you get the option of specifying a different AMI than our default (for example). Is that the source of confusion?